# If $X,Y$ are random variables and $Y\sim\mathcal N(x,\sigma^2)$ if $X=x$, are we able to conclude $Y-X\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, markov-process

Let $\sigma>0$ and $$Q(x,\;\cdot\;):=\mathcal N(x,\sigma^2)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$ Note that $Q$ is a [Markov kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Definition) on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Now, let $X,Y$ be real-valued random variables on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$. Let $X_\ast\operatorname P$ and $Y_\ast\operatorname P$ denote the distribution of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and asume that $$Y_\ast\operatorname P=(X_\ast\operatorname P)Q,$$ where the right-hand side denotes the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Composition_of_kernels) of $X_\ast\operatorname P$ and $Q$.

> Are we able to show that $(Y-X)_\ast\operatorname P=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Intuitively, if $X=x\in\mathbb R$, then $Y\sim\mathcal N(x,\sigma^2)$ and it's a well-known fact that $Y-x\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Isn't the expected value of $Y-x$ equal to $-x$?

Comment: @uniquesolution No, we should have $\operatorname E\left[Y\mid X=x\right]=x.$

Comment: Since the conditional distribution of $Y-X$ given $X=x$ is independent of $x$, then $Y-X$ is independent of $X$ and has this distribution (the particular distribution is not important).

Comment: @zhoraster Sorry, I think I don't understand what you mean. Clearly, a random variable is independent of a constant, but how do you conclude that $Y-X$ is independent of $X$?

Comment: I mean this: two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff the conditional distribution $F_y$ of $X$ given $Y=y$ does not depend on $y$, i.e. $F_y\equiv F$. In this case also $F$ is the (unconditional) distribution of $X$.

Comment: @zhoraster I see. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mentioned property of the normal distribution, we know that $$\int 1_B(y-x)\:\mathcal N(x,\sigma^2)({\rm d}y)=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\tag1.$$ Now, it's easy to see that $$\operatorname P\left[(X,Y)\in\;\cdot\;\right]=X_\ast\operatorname P\otimes\:Q\tag2$$ and hence \begin{equation}\begin{split}\operatorname P\left[Y-X\in B\right]&=\int\operatorname P\left[X\in{\rm d}x\right]\int Q(x,{\rm d}y)1_B(y-x)\\&=\int\operatorname P\left[X\in{\rm d}x\right]\int\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)({\rm d}y)1_B(y)=\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)(B)\end{split}\tag3\end{equation} for all $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** : We can prove that $ Y-X \sim \mathcal N( 0, \sigma^2)$.

**Proof** : To see it, the key is to write law of $Y-X$ using the expectation of the conditional probability knowing $X$:

$$P(Y-X < t) = E( P( Y -X <  t | X ) ) $$

Then, notice that $P( Y - X <  t | X )$ (which is a function of X) actually does not depend on $X$ :

Let $N_a$ denote a Gaussian variable $N_a \sim \mathcal N( a, \sigma^2)$ (not related to $X$ and $Y$).
$$P( Y - X< t | X = x_0 ) = P( Y - x_0 <  t | X = x_0 ) $$ 
$$ = P( N_{x_0} - x_0 < t )$$
$$ = P( N_0 < t )  $$ 
This last term is constant (i.e. does not depend on $x_0$), therefore its expectation is the same.

$$ E( P( N_0 < t ) ) = P( N_0 < t )  $$

We just have proven that $$P(Y-X < t) = P( N_0 < t )  $$

Therefore, $$ Y - X \sim N_0 $$

Comment: I didn't claim that $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$, but $Y-X\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. And that's obviously the case if $X$ is a constant.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, I updated my answer.